# Building a link with l() and t()

Tags: navigation

I'm trying to build this:

```
<a href="/en/webform?edit[submitted][nameofthepet_webform_fieldset][webform_nume_animal_comp]=NAME-OF-PET" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Adopt NAME-OF-PET</a>
```

the code I'm using:

```
$adopt_me_link_male = l(t("Adopt !name",
 array('!name' => $node->field_pet_name['und'][0]['safe_value']), array('context' => 'Male pet name')), 'node/163', array('query' => array('edit[submitted][nameofthepet_webform_fieldset][webform_nume_animal_comp]=' => $node->field_pet_name['und'][0]['safe_value'])), array('attributes' => array('class' => array('btn', 'btn-primary', 'btn-xs'),),) );
```

The above code generates the link but I have two problems:

1. the link looks like this:

   [Adopt NAME-OF-PET](/en/webform?edit%5Bsubmitted%5D%5Bnameofthepet_webform_fieldset%5D%5Bwebform_nume_animal_comp%5D%3D=NAME-OF-PET)
2. there's no css class applied to the anchor

Why the classes are not applied and the link looks so messy?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug in your URL snippet (syntax error), so I'm writing the code.

```
<?php 
$adopt_me_link_male = l(
  t('Adopt @name', 
    array('@name' => $node->field_pet_name['und'][0]['safe_value']), //t() function replacements array
    array('context' => 'Male pet name') //t() function options array. Not necessary in this case though.
    ),
  'node/163', // l() function - URL
  array(
    'query' => array(
      'edit[submitted][nameofthepet_webform_fieldset][webform_nume_animal_comp]' => $node->field_pet_name['und'][0]['safe_value'],
    ),
    'attributes' => array(
      'class' => array('btn', 'btn-primary', 'btn-xs'),
    ),
  )
);

?>
```

In this example, I changed `!name` to `@name` for the security (Read `t()` function documentation). Also, if you want to use HTML inside the anchor (say, an image), you have to pass `'html' => TRUE` the last parameter array in the `l()` function (add it along with the `attributes` and `query` array keys).